# PhoneGap cross-platform plugins and TextToSpeech

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, phonegap-plugins, text-to-speech

I would like to create a cross-platform app (PhoneGap + HTML + Javascript) with the capability of **TextToSpeech** offline.

I've found only two old Phonegap plugins for Android, but nothing that runs on iOS or WP8.
Is there any other PhoneGap plugins or pure Javascript libraries for TTS? I've found `meSpeak.js` but I would like something more natural/professional.

Thank you in advance.